# catching exception with cached_property

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

i am trying to catch exceptions using `decorator` for a `cached_property` https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/commit/fa7733e075da0d790d809aa3d2f53071897e6f76

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property

I would like to do something as easy as follows, but this doesn't work

```
from pprint import pprint
import time
from cached_property import cached_property

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def catch_my_exceptions(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except MyException as e:
            cls = args[0]
            err = 'Found error at {}: {}'.format(time.asctime(), e)
            cls.error_msgs.append(err)
            print(err)
            return
    return wrapped

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    @cached_property
    @catch_my_exceptions
    def is_cache_working(self):
        self.vars[time.asctime()] = True
        time.sleep(3)
        print('running cache runner')
        return time.asctime()

fo = Foo()
for i in range(3):
    print(fo.is_cache_working)
    pprint(fo.vars)


# This doesn't trigger caching

running cache runner
Thu Feb 23 21:45:15 2017
{'Thu Feb 23 21:45:11 2017': True}
running cache runner
Thu Feb 23 21:45:18 2017
{'Thu Feb 23 21:45:11 2017': True, 'Thu Feb 23 21:45:15 2017': True}
running cache runner
Thu Feb 23 21:45:21 2017
{'Thu Feb 23 21:45:11 2017': True,
 'Thu Feb 23 21:45:15 2017': True,
 'Thu Feb 23 21:45:18 2017': True}



# Current solution that works:
```

My hack around this is do the following. Can someone suggest me a better way. also how would I pass a list of exceptions to this `my_cached_decorator`

```
import time
from pprint import pprint
from cached_property import cached_property

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

class my_cached_property(cached_property):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(func)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        try:
            super(self.__class__, self).__get__(obj, cls)
        except MyException as e:
            err = 'Found error at {}: {}'.format(time.asctime(), e)
            print(err)
            value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = None
            return value

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    @my_cached_property
    def is_cache_working(self):
        self.vars[time.asctime()] = True
        time.sleep(3)
        print('running cache runner')
        raise MyException('fooobar')
        return time.asctime()

fo = Foo()
for i in range(3):
    print(fo.is_cache_working)
    pprint(fo.vars)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the best solution, but you will have access to the inner function returned from the decorator to the caller and also from within the decorator's closure.

Example:

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            wrapper.__dict__.setdefault('errors', []).append(e)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def raiser():
    raise Exception('Oh no!')

> raiser()
> raiser.errors
[Exception('Oh no!')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out the problem, and it's in the way that cached_property works. To cache it, it writes the value onto the instance under the same name as the function it wrapped. The problem is that the name of the function that it's wrapping has the name "wrapped", from your decorator. So, if you accessed fo.wrapped after the initial fo.is_cache_working, you'd get your cached result.

There is no easy way to mix the two ideas together. The simplest solution is to write your own cached_property that stores the value on itself:

```
class cached_property(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        # you can store other function attributes here - such as __doc__ - if you want
        self.values = {}

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance in self.values:
            return self.values[instance]
        else:
            value = self.values[instance] = self.func(instance)
            return value
```

Comment: Or, in your decorator, use the `functools.wraps` decorator to decorate your `wrapped` function. So, add an import to `functools` at the top, and add `functools.wraps(fn)` on the line before your `wrapped` definition. This changes the `__name__` of `wrapped` to have the same name as `fn`, along with a few other things.